# JAVA simple threads, magic number question (cant stop threads)

Tags: java, multithreading, android-studio

I have this assignment for android studio where I am running 2 threads, both generate random numbers and if one of the numbers is a magic number, it stops both threads and it displays the magic number on the screen. I'm not concerned about the UI elements yet, so lets not worry about that, I'm only focused on trying to stop the threads because I cant use thread.stop and to be honest this seems simple but after trying many methods I don't get how to stop the threads from running after finding a magic number, if anyone can show me how its done I would be able to understand it more. Here are the full instructions and the code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.Random;

/*
 1. The main activity creates and starts two threads using one Runnable object. Give each thread a name when it is created.
 The main activity controls the UI presentation. While waiting, it shows a ‘rotating’ progress bar.

2.  Each background thread does the following:
a.   sleep for 1 second,
b.  generate a random four-digit number,
c.  write the number and the thread’s name to the log,
d.   send a message containing the number to the main thread, then repeat the cycle.

3.  When the main activity receives a message containing a number, it determines if the number is ‘magic’. If it is ‘magic’,
it stops both background threads and displays the value of the magic number on the screen.  (Don’t use thread.stop() to stop the threads.)

A magic number is a four digit value that either (1) is a multiple of seven or (2) is a multiple of four and ‘2’ is its last digit.

4.  The first magic number written to the UI cannot be changed.
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MagicNumbers();
    }

    private static int limit = 100000;
    static int low = 1000;
    static int high = 9999;
    static String getThreadName;
    static String currentNumber;
    static Runnable create = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            for(int i = 0; i < MainActivity.limit; ++i) {
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);   //makes threads sleep for 1 second
                }catch(InterruptedException e) {}
                getThreadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();   //gets the name of the current thread running
                Random r = new Random();                 //calculates random number
                int result = r.nextInt(high - low) + low;
                check_magic(result,getThreadName);
            }
        }
    };

    public static synchronized void check_magic(Integer value, String threadName) {
        if (value % 7 == 0 || value % 4 == 0 && value % 10 == 2) {
            currentNumber="MAGIC NUMBER GENERATED: "+value+", created by "+threadName;
            Log.i("Program2", currentNumber);
        }
        else {
            currentNumber="Number: "+value+", created by "+threadName;
            Log.i("Program2", currentNumber);
        }
    }

    public void MagicNumbers() {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(create);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(create);
        thread1.setName("ONE");
        thread2.setName("TWO");
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();

        try {
            thread1.join();
            thread2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException var7) {}
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You can stop a thread using `Thread.interrupt()`.  However, if you are going to do that you need to fix your code so that it DOES NOT catch and ignore `InterruptedException` in the thread you are interrupting.  It looks like there are other problems in your code too ... per the requirements ... but you may simply not have implemented them all yet.

Comment: I have tried using Thread.interrupt(), I still cant get the program to stop the threads because it does not allow me to use thread.join() without try and catch. The other requirements are about UI so I am not too worried about that.

Comment: It should work ... if you do it correctly.  Please show us your (complete) attempt using interrupt, so that we can see what you actually did and advise you on how to fix it.

Comment: It does not let me run at all without try/catch statement for thread1.join(); and thread2.join(); But I am trying to use `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` inside the IF statement in check_magic

Comment: I cannot see the code you are talking about.  If you want us to help you with it, we need to >>see<< it.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm only focused on trying to stop the threads because I cant use thread.stop and to be honest this seems simple but after trying many methods I don't get how to stop the threads from running after finding a magic number,

There are a number of ways that you can communicate between the threads so that they can tell each other that they have found the magic number.  The easiest would be for them to both share a `volatile boolean found` field.  So the `create` class would have:

```
 private volatile boolean found;
```

At the loop would be:

```
// run until down or if the other thread finds the winning magic
for(int i = 0; i < MainActivity.limit && !found; ++i) {
```

The check code would look like:

```
    if (value % 7 == 0 || value % 4 == 0 && value % 10 == 2) {
        currentNumber="MAGIC NUMBER GENERATED: "+value+", created by "+threadName;
        Log.i("Program2", currentNumber);
        found = true;
    } else {
       ...
    }
```

Because the field is `volatile`, both threads can see the other thread's update and will stop their own loop.

Couple comments:

- storing things in static fields inside of a `synchronized` method is not a good pattern.
  Even if the one thread finds the magic, the other thread will overwrite the static fields.   This might be the source of your problem.  I would create a `FindMagicRunnable` class that implements `Runnable`.  Both classes would need to share the same `found` but they should have their own `currentNumber` and `threadName` instance fields.
- `getThreadName` is the name of a method not a field.  The field is `threadName`.

So something like:

```
// both threads would set this, you could also use a shared AtomicBoolean
static volatile boolean found;
....
private static class FindMagicRunnable implements Runnable {
    String threadName;
    int winningMagic;
    ...
}

    FindMagicRunnable run1 = new FindMagicRunnable();
    FindMagicRunnable run2 = new FindMagicRunnable();
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(run1);
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(run2);
    thread1.setName("ONE");
    thread2.setName("TWO");
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();

    try {
        thread1.join();
        thread2.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException var7) {}
    
    if (run1.winningMagic != 0) {
       // thread1 is the winner
    } else {
       // thread2 is the winner
    }
```

There are some race conditions with this implementation if both threads find the winning number at the same time.  If you want to get it perfect then you should use an [`AtomicReference`](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/atomicreference.html) and set both the name and the winning number using the `testAndSet(...)` atomically.